# Tree Implementation giving segmentation fault(core dump) error c++ 11

Tags: c++, tree, segmentation-fault

Recently, I coded linked list with C++11. Using those concepts, I tried to code tree{a very basic tree} implementation in C++11. But it is giving me a Segmentation fault. I checked online and found out that it happens when the program tries to write a read access memory or tries to access free memory, but I can't figure out how it's happening here. Please help..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    node *left;
    node *right;
    int key;
};
class tree{
    public:
    node *root;
    tree(){
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
    }
    node *createnode(int data){
        node *temp=new node;
        temp->key=data;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        return temp;
    }
};
int main(){
    tree t;
    node *root;
    root=t.createnode(1);
    //root->left=t.createnode(2);
    //root->right=t.createnode(3);
    //root->left->left=t.createnode(9);
    //root->left->right=t.createnode(7);
return 0;
}
```

[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZkNB.png)

Comment: In `tree()` you access variable `root`, but you didn't initialize it.

Answer (score 5):

`t.root` is uninitialized, so writing to `root->left` and `root->right` in `tree`'s constructor invokes undefined behavior.

Right now, your `tree` class doesn't really make much sense.  It contains a `root` node pointer, but you never use it.  `createnode` could just be a free function or a static member of `node`.  Better would be to encapsulate nodes entirely and just have `tree` have an `insert` method that takes an `int`, creates a new node, and inserts it at the appropriate place in the tree.

Comment: Thanks, i initailised it and it worked. But I didn't get your last sentence.  What do you mean by encapsulating node entirely? Can you give me an example..

Comment: @JimmyFails I mean make `node` private to `tree` so users of the `tree` class don't need to know about it or interact with it at all.  Make it an implementation detail rather than part of `tree`'s interface.  For example, `std::map` has a `node` class that it uses internally, but to use `std::map` you don't have to know or think about nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the constructor:

```
class tree{
    public:
    node *root;
    tree(){
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
    }
```

You declare `root` in the class, but you never initialize it. So when you dereference it in the body of the constructor, you are dereferencing a garbage pointer that could point to anything. 
 Strictly speaking, what you are doing there is Undefined Behaviour and the compiler is well within its right to generate *whatever it likes* or even nothing at all for that bit of code.

Unrelated nitpick: don't use `NULL` in new code, use `nullptr`.